# postgreSQL importing csv file in pgadmin4

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

Is it possible to have a stored procedure in importing a csv file to postgreSQL? Does the simple copy function enough? However, I have like 10 csv files to import with same column names and my instructor wants us to use a stored procedure zz

```
CREATE TABLE Sales(
    OrderID INTEGER,
    Product VARCHAR(100),
    Quantity INTEGER,
    PriceEach NUMERIC(10,2),
    OrderDate TIMESTAMP,
    PurchaseAddress VARCHAR(100)
);
```

```
--COPY the records from CSV
COPY Sales(OrderID,Product,Quantity,PriceEach,OrderDate,PurchaseAddress)
FROM 'C:\sampledb\Sales.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: That will work fine if the file is on the database server.

Comment: As long as the server user can access and has permissions on  `'C:\sampledb\Sales.csv'`.

Comment: Yes yes. I figured it out on how to use stored procedure for that hehe